# Enable to connect to remote server using ssh but i can connect one remote server

Tags: server, ssh, security, remote

When I am connecting to remote server using ip address, I can connect to 192.168.12.141, but I cannot connect to any another remote server. Example: 192.168.12.12, 13, 18 etc... 
How can I get permission or change the permission. Can anyone help please

```
username@cl1:~$ ssh 192.168.12.12 -l administrator

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!

Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!

It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.

The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
ee:f8:02:53:eb:26:16:98:c7:22:ce:59:ca:af:d4:f6.

Please contact your system administrator.

Add correct host key in /home/EXAMPLE/username/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.

Offending key in /home/EXAMPLE/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1

RSA host key for 192.168.12.12 has changed and you have requested strict checking.

Host key verification failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you reinstall system but your `/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts` is old. 
Remove `known_hosts` and you will be able to connect to host, but you will must accept new key on first connect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the file `$HOME/.rss/know_hosts`. Some entries in the file are not correct, you have to remove them so that at the next connection will be re-created.
You can edit the file manually by removing entries with a text editor, the format of the file is:

```
<servername,ip> ssh-rsa host <RSA key>
```

delete the row corresponding to the server.

Or by using the command:

```
 ssh-keygen-R ip-server
```

Now, you can connect to the host without a problem.

Refer to `man ssh-keygen` for more help.